# Using scipy.optimize.broyden2 with a function which receives several parameters

Tags: python, scipy

I want to use [scipy.optimize.broyden2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.broyden2.html), the problem is that my function doesn't just take an array as argument, but a lot more parameters.

What should I do? Define global variables?

These are my functions:

```
def F(S, I, R, alpha, beta):
    return [- beta * S * I, beta * S * I - alpha * R, alpha * R]

def euler(xi, xf, m, F, initial_values, alpha, beta):
    h = (xf - xi) / m

    t = np.linspace(xi, xf, m + 1)
    t = np.delete(t, 0)

    vect_y = [initial_values[0], initial_values[1], initial_values[2]]

    for i in range(len(t)):
        y_actual = [sum(x) for x in zip(vect_y, [element * h for element in F(vect_y[0], vect_y[1], vect_y[2], alpha, beta)])]
        vect_y = y_actual

    return vect_y
```

I want to use `broyden2` with `euler`, where `x0` would be `initial_values`.

Comment: defining global variables is generally not the Pythonic solution. Without knowing more about your problem, the Pythonic solution is probably to define a function which takes your parameters, creates an array to use `scipy.optimize.broyden2` on, and then returns the result of `scipy.optimize.broyden2`. But hard to say more without knowing anything about your parameters or problem.

Comment: You can refactor to use *args or something like that. Can you show us your current code? Hard to theory craft, better to see the actual problem.

Comment: @mwm314 I added my functions.

Comment: Many of the `optimize` functions take a `args` parameter, a tuple, that is passed through to your function.  I don't see that in this case.  So you'll need to define a cover function (maybe a lambda) that just takes the optimization variable as argument (initial values), and takes the rest from the environment (global or function local).

Answer (score 2):

As was suggested in comments, you can use an auxiliary function that unpacks the list of arguments using `*list` syntax, and calls your main function with that. A minimal example is shown below, where `f` is the function whose root is being found.

```
from scipy.optimize import broyden2
def f(x, y, z):
    return [x-1, y-2, z-3]
broyden2(lambda X: f(*X), [0, 0, 0])
```

Output: `array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])`